# image not available when i upload new image Fabricjs

Tags: javascript, angular, fabricjs

currently iam facing one issue if i upload a image the image getting upload. second time when i am trying to upload the image. The image is upload but the previous image is not showing up there only the current image is showing but in the preview i can see the previous image for example.

[image]

now I am uploading some more images in the left hand side the previous uploaded images not showing

[image]

Here is my html

```
      <div class="panel-body text-center">
    <img id="testImage"  (dragover)="false"(dragend)="false"
    (drop)="handleDrop($event)" class="images-item-upload" *ngFor='let item of urls' [src]="item.url"  (click)="onClik(item);"/>
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-block file-container">
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-upload"></i> Choose a file
      <input type='file' [disabled]="urls.length >= 16"  multiple (change)="readUrl($event);">
    </label>

  </div>
```

Here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h3hdyr) link for the reference

In the upload history the previous upload images not showing only the current upload only showing

What I am doing wrong here why the image is not displaying

Ts code

```
     addImage(canvasInst, imageUrls) {
      if(imageUrls){
            fabric.Image.fromURL(imageUrls, img => {
            var oImg = img;
            oImg.scaleToWidth(250);
            oImg.scaleToHeight(250);
            canvasInst.centerObject(oImg);
            canvasInst.add(oImg).renderAll();
            canvasInst.setActiveObject(oImg);
            // canvasInst.toDataURL({ format: "png", quality: 0.8 });
            });
            this.updateLayers();
        }
  }
```

Comment: please don't close the question i am struggling

Answer (score 0):

I got the anwser in my readUrl i have to remove my

this.urls= []